# BSON Message To Map in JAVA

Tags: java, serialization, redis, bson

We are currently sending messages to a Redis Queue, which is being picked up by our JAVA application.

Anyone have an idea how to convert the `BSON` message to a `Map` in JAVA?

Here is an example MSG in BSON we pop from the Redis queue:

```
\x16\x00\x00\x00\x02hello\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00world\x00\x00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MongoDB Driver:

Parse your BSON data just like this:

```
    RawDBObject obj(your ByteBuffer buf );
    obj.toMap();
```

done.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/com/mongodb/RawDBObject.java

or BSON official site may help:

http://bsonspec.org/#/implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BSON parser to parse your BSON input.  Google gives me [bson4jackson](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/bson4jackson) but I have never tried it myself.

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/com/mongodb/RawDBObject.java might also be an option (Google, again).

Comment: I have been trying to use the MongoDB BSON parser with no luck.. Is there anybody with experience with MongoDB BSON or bson4jackson that could provide some example code on parsing my example BSON string above? Much Appreciated.